# Filter directories from list of files and directories

Tags: linux, command-line, path, xargs, filter

I have a file containing full path names of files an directories.

From this list I would like to filter out any pathnames that reference directories so that I am left with a list containing only file paths.

Can anybody think of an elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  [ -d "$file" ] || printf '%s\n' "$file"
done <input_file
```

Would print the files that are not determined to be of type *directory* (or symlink to directory). It would leave all other type of files (regular, symlink (except to directories), sockets, pipes...) and those for which the type cannot be determined (for instance because they don't exist or are in directories which you don't have search permission to).

Some variations depending on what you meant *by file and directory* (*directory* is one of many types of files on Unix):

- the file *exists* (after symlink resolution) and is not of type *directory*:

  ```
  [ -e "$file" ] && [ ! -d "$file" ] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
  ```
- file *exists* and is a *regular* file (after symlink resolution):

  ```
  [ -f "$file" ] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
  ```
- file *exists* and is a *regular* file before symlink resolution (excludes symlinks):

  ```
  [ -f "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
  ```
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `file` contains one file path per line, with `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(f)^"$(<file)"}(N^/)
```

would print those that do exist (that we can tell exist) and are not determined to be of type *directory* (change `/` to `-/` to also discard symlinks to directories).

Since you mention `xargs`, with the GNU implementation (for `-d` and `-r`), and assuming none of the file paths start with `-` or are `find` predicates (like `!`) you could do:

```
xargs -rd '\n' sh -xc 'exec find "$@" -prune ! -type d' sh < file
```

Replace `-type` with `-xtype` (assuming GNU `find`) to also exclude symlinks to directories.